# Infinite Google Places Instances

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, location, google-places-api

My database records are printed into a table with the values in input's. For every record I need the Location field to be autocompleted by Google their API.

**HTML:**

```
<input name="edit_airplane[1][location]" type="text" class="airplane_location" value="Balmaceda">
```

**Javascript:**

```
function initAutocomplete() {
    var airplane_location_field = jQuery( '.airplane_location');

    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete( airplane_location_field ), {types : ['geocode']} );
    autocomplete.addListener( 'place_changed', function() {
        /* 
           Whenever the value of the location field has changed. I need to
           Create a new input field which is hidden with the full address 
           Of the selected google autocomplete location.
        */
    });
}
```

What would be the best way to check which input field has changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did alot of research and eventually came to this solution.

```
function initAutocomplete() {
    // All of the airplanes_location input fields are combined.
    var airplane_location_fields = jQuery( '.airplane_location' );

    // For each location form field 
    airplane_location_fields.each( function() {
        var _this = jQuery( this ), autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete( this );
        _this.data('autocomplete', autocomplete);

        // For each input field I stored the autocomplete object into .data; 
        _this.data('autocomplete').addListener( 'place_changed', function() {
            getPlaceData( _this );
        } );
    } );
}


function getPlaceData( input ) {
    // In this function I checked the input.data('autocomplete');
}
```